# Disassebling of Debian file for extract opcodes

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, disassembly

I know debian files are just packages. But I need to have opcodes for some analysis. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg -x name_of_deb.deb /tmp/datadir
```

while take the contents of `name_of_deb` and stick them in `/tmp/datadir`.

You can build `dpkg` from source on almost any system if you are trying to unpack a Deb on a non-Debian system, or if you have `ar` and `tar`, there's a more complex approach.

Then you can use something like `objdump --disassemble` to dump the binaries in /tmp/datadir/usr/bin and /tmp/datadir/usr/lib

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very useful!!